# Fourier Sine Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

There is a question from my book which I find hard. Here it goes:

> Consider
>   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-v_0\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \quad\quad(x>0)$$
>   $$u(0,t)=0$$
>   $$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
>   Show that the Fourier sine transform does not yield an immidiate solution

Am I correct saying the Sine transform is as follows?:

> $$\frac{\partial \bar{U}}{\partial t}=k\left.(\frac{2}{\pi}\omega f(0)-\omega^2\bar{U}\right.)+v_0\omega C[f]$$

Thnx in advance

Comment: What is the meaning of "does not yield an immidiate solution" in this question claimed?

Comment: I think an immidiate solution means a solution which can be made with little steps and such that you only need to plug the values of the constants in order to get a physical answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying Fourier sine transform on $t$ , the term of $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ will relate to Fourier cosine transform rather than that of Fourier sine transform; when applying Fourier sine transform on $x$ , the term of $\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$ will relate to Fourier sine transform but the term of $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ will relate to Fourier cosine transform rather than that of Fourier sine transform. So we cannot solve this PDE by Fourier sine transform unless $v_0=0$ . The statement of this question stated is partially correct.

Separation of variables has no such problem, as the concept of separation of variables is to choose the most suitable kernel transform type according to the solution forms of the ODEs separated rather than applying fixed kernel transform type.

Case $1$: $\text{Re}(kt)\geq0$

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)=kX''(x)T(t)-v_0X'(x)T(t)$

$X(x)T'(t)=(kX''(x)-v_0X'(x))T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{kX''(x)-v_0X'(x)}{X(x)}=-\dfrac{4k^2s^2+v_0^2}{4k}$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-\dfrac{4k^2s^2+v_0^2}{4k}\\kX''(x)-v_0X'(x)+\dfrac{4k^2s^2+v_0^2}{4k}X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-\frac{t(4k^2s^2+v_0^2)}{4k}}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)e^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}\sin xs+c_2(s)e^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1xe^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}+c_2e^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{\frac{2v_0x-t(4k^2s^2+v_0^2)}{4k}}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{\frac{2v_0x-t(4k^2s^2+v_0^2)}{4k}}\cos xs~ds$

$u(0,t)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-\frac{t(4k^2s^2+v_0^2)}{4k}}ds=0$

$C_2(s)=0$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{\frac{2v_0x-t(4k^2s^2+v_0^2)}{4k}}\sin xs~ds$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}\sin xs~ds=f(x)$

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds=f(x)e^{-\frac{v_0x}{2k}}$

$\mathcal{F}_{s,s\to x}\{C_1(s)\}=f(x)e^{-\frac{v_0x}{2k}}$

$C_1(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\left\{f(x)e^{-\frac{v_0x}{2k}}\right\}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\left\{f(x)e^{-\frac{v_0x}{2k}}\right\}e^{\frac{2v_0x-t(4k^2s^2+v_0^2)}{4k}}\sin xs~ds$

Case $2$: $\text{Re}(kt)\leq0$

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)=kX''(x)T(t)-v_0X'(x)T(t)$

$X(x)T'(t)=(kX''(x)-v_0X'(x))T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{kX''(x)-v_0X'(x)}{X(x)}=\dfrac{4k^2s^2-v_0^2}{4k}$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{4k^2s^2-v_0^2}{4k}\\kX''(x)-v_0X'(x)-\dfrac{4k^2s^2-v_0^2}{4k}X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{\frac{t(4k^2s^2-v_0^2)}{4k}}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)e^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}\sinh xs+c_2(s)e^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}\cosh xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1xe^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}+c_2e^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{\frac{2v_0x+t(4k^2s^2-v_0^2)}{4k}}\sinh xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{\frac{2v_0x+t(4k^2s^2-v_0^2)}{4k}}\cosh xs~ds$

$u(0,t)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{\frac{t(4k^2s^2-v_0^2)}{4k}}ds=0$

$C_2(s)=0$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{\frac{2v_0x+t(4k^2s^2-v_0^2)}{4k}}\sinh xs~ds$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{\frac{v_0x}{2k}}\sinh xs~ds=f(x)$

$-i\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin ixs~ds=f(x)e^{-\frac{v_0x}{2k}}$

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds=if(-ix)e^{\frac{iv_0x}{2k}}$

$\mathcal{F}_{s,s\to x}\{C_1(s)\}=if(-ix)e^{\frac{iv_0x}{2k}}$

$C_1(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\left\{if(-ix)e^{\frac{iv_0x}{2k}}\right\}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\left\{if(-ix)e^{\frac{iv_0x}{2k}}\right\}e^{\frac{2v_0x+t(4k^2s^2-v_0^2)}{4k}}\sinh xs~ds$

Comment: I do not understand the justification for using separation of variables here.

Comment: Doraemonpaul can you explain why the sine-transform of this function gives a problem? You just solved it, but that was not the question.